# sequelize.sync({force:true}) not working and the logging of method is empty

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I've seen a ton of questions that appears when I was writing this issue. none of them had the same problem and after 20h straight trying to solve this i'm quite stressed, so sorry if I didn't see a similar issue. Ok, the problem is the following: I'm using nodejs,expressjs(4.17),sequelize-cli(6.2.0)and sequelizejs(6.3.5) to do a server and communicate with mysql(mysql2 2.1.0) and for some reason when I use the function `sequelize.sync()` (having or not the `{force:true}`) it just doesn't update the tables inside the database, which is already created, it does nothing, no errors, no warnings, just not doing  what's supposed to do.
I created the models using `npx sequelize  model:generate --name ... --attributes ...`  so the migrations created does not have anything I manually inserted in it, because I searched that's not supposed to change the migrations files. Then I ran `npx sequelize db:migrate` to up the migrations to database and finally did some changes to models that didn't synced.

***here is the server.js code:***

```js
const http = require('http')
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const app = require('./src/app')
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
const server = http.createServer(app)

const contatos = require('./src/_db/models/contatos')
const corretores = require('./src/_db/models/corretores')
const imoveis = require('./src/_db/models/imoveis')
const tipoimovel = require('./src/_db/models/tipoimovel')

const sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.DB_NAME, process.env.DB_USERNAME, process.env.DB_PASSWORD, {
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: "mysql" /* one of 'mysql' | 'mariadb' | 'postgres' | 'mssql' */,
    logging: console.log,  
})

sequelize.authenticate().then( () => {
    console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
    

    sequelize.sync({logging:console.log, force:true})
        .then(() => {
            // console.log(`Database & tables created!`);
            return server.listen(port)
        }).catch((error)=>{
            return console.error(error);
        });

}).catch((error) => {
    console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', error);
})
```

***The code of my app.js:***

```js
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const morgan = require('morgan')
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const app = express()

app.use(morgan('dev'))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    res.header(
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
        'Origin, X-Requested-With, Accept, Authorization'
    )
    if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE, GET')
        return res.status(200).json({})
    }
    next()
})



app.use((req, res, next) => {
    const error = new Error('Not found')
    error.status = 404
    next(error)
})

app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
    res.status(error.status || 500)
    res.json({
        error: {
            message: error.message
        }
    })
})

module.exports = app
```

***The console result of all:***

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...  
[nodemon] starting 'node server.js'    
Executing (default): SELECT 1+1 AS result     
Connection has been established successfully.     
Executing (default): SELECT 1+1 AS result     
Database & tables created!
```

***And finally an example of Model that I'm trying to update the database with, already with changes I've made:***

```js
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class tipoImovel extends Model {
    
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
      this.hasOne(models.Imoveis)
    }
  };
  tipoImovel.init({
    tipoNome: {type:DataTypes.STRING,allowNull:false},
    tipoSigla: {type: DataTypes.STRING(2),allowNull:false,unique:true}
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'tipoImovel',
  });
  return tipoImovel;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used sync like this, and it worked for me. You can try it as solution if you want.

```js
'use strict';
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const cls = require('cls-hooked');
const namespace = cls.createNamespace('my-very-own-namespace');
Sequelize.useCLS(namespace);
const config = require("../environments/index");

// server connection settings
var db_instance = new Sequelize(config.DB.database, config.DB.username, config.DB.password, {
  host: config.DB.host,
  dialect: config.DB.dialect,
  define: {
    timestamps: false
  },
  logging: false
});

var sequelize = db_instance;

// checks the database connectivity
sequelize
  .authenticate()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
  });


const db = {};

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

// create the modal instance 
db.users = require('../model/users.model')(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.country = require('../model/country.model')(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.state = require('../model/state.model')(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.city = require('../model/city.model')(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.verify_otp = require('../model/verify_otp.model')(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.organizations = require('../model/organizations.model')(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.features = require('../model/features.model')(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.user_features = require('../model/user_features.model')(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.roles = require('../model/roles.model')(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.user_roles = require('../model/user_roles.model')(sequelize, Sequelize);



db.sequelize.sync({ force: true }).then(() => {
  console.log("Drop and re-sync db.");
});

module.exports = db;
```

Comment: hello, thanks for the help, but it was something I tried before using`{force:true}` and before I moved the `sequelize.sync()` inside the authenticate, it has absolutely no effect or change, I suppose the problem is  something related to how I imported libs or how I installed them. because it happens in both of my API's projects. The other project I used Koa instead of Express, idk if this has something to do.

Comment: I have updated the answer you can try that one also

Comment: oook, I'll try. I was struggling to import the models haha.

Comment: If the answer helped you with your problem I would really appreciate it if you could mark it as the accepted answer

Comment: yeah, I'll try it now, sorry for long time. I was busy with other stuff

Comment: ok, just tried, same result, nothing changed in migrations nor in database, the relationship between tables was not added, unfortunately I'm gonna have to change directly in migrations, to keep going with it :c ... thanks for helping!

Comment: ok... News... this time I didn't miss a crucial part of code, and it worked! gonna mark your answer as accepted! haha, And I just want an explanation about that models import lines there, passing sequelize and Sequelize, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`db.sequelize.sync({ force: true }).then(() => {});`

> Force true will turncate the table. It will definitely update the
> table with new column but data will be lost. It should work with alter
> true only